# A basic question on martingales and filtrations

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

It is stated as a Corollary in a book that if $\tau$ is any stopping time and $M_t$ is a martingale with respect to $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}_t,\mathbb{P})$, then so is $M_{t\wedge\tau}$. However, I am mainly concerned with the filtrations associated with the martingales $M_{t\wedge\tau}$. I know that (from the Theorem in the book from which the Corollary is deduced without stating its proof) for any $0\leq s\leq t$ we have $$\mathbb{E}[M_{t\wedge \tau} \mid \mathcal{F}_{s\wedge \tau}] = M_{s\wedge \tau}.$$ But I think the author means that $M_{t\wedge \tau}$ is a martingale associated with the same filtration as that of $M_t$ (which is $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}$), in that case, I really didn't see how one can prove that $$\mathbb{E}[M_{t\wedge \tau} \mid \mathcal{F}_s] = M_{s\wedge \tau}$$ for any $0\leq s \leq t$. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's effectively just a computation:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[M_{t \wedge \tau} | \mathcal F_s] &= \mathbb{E}[M_{t \wedge \tau}1_{\tau \le s} | \mathcal F_s] + \mathbb{E}[M_{t \wedge \tau}1_{\tau > s} | \mathcal F_s] \\
&= M_\tau 1_{\tau \le s} + \mathbb{E}[M_{t \wedge \tau}1_{\tau > s} | \mathcal F_s]
\end{align*}

so we just need to show $\mathbb{E}[M_{t \wedge \tau}1_{\tau > s} | \mathcal F_s] = M_s 1_{\tau > s}.$  Let $A \in \mathcal F_s$, and notice $A \cap \{\tau > s \} \in \mathcal F_{\tau \wedge s}$ so we have

\begin{align*}
\int_A M_{t \wedge \tau}1_{\tau > s} dP &= \int_{A \cap \{\tau > s \}} M_{t \wedge \tau} dP \\
&= \int_{A \cap \{\tau > s \}} \mathbb{E}[M_{t \wedge \tau}|\mathcal F_{\tau \wedge s}] dP \\
&= \int_{A \cap \{\tau > s \}} M_{s \wedge \tau} dP \\
&= \int_A M_{s \wedge \tau}1_{\tau > s} dP \\
&= \int_A M_{s}1_{\tau > s} dP
\end{align*}

and by definition of conditional expectation we conclude $\mathbb{E}[M_{t \wedge \tau}1_{\tau > s} | \mathcal F_s] = M_s 1_{\tau > s}.$  Therefore

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[M_{t \wedge \tau} | \mathcal F_s] &= M_\tau 1_{\tau \le s} + M_s 1_{\tau > s} \\
&= M_{s \wedge \tau}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for your great answer!

Comment: Can you clarify the 1st to 2nd line of the computation: swapping out $M_{t\wedge \tau}$ with $\mathbb E[M_{t\wedge \tau} \mid \mathcal F_{\tau\wedge s}]$?

Comment: It's from the definition of conditional expectation: We are integrating $X$ over $A \cap \{ \tau > s \}$ which is in $\mathcal F_{\tau \wedge s}$, so it's the same as if we integrate $\mathbb{E}[X | \mathcal F_{\tau \wedge s}]$ over $A \cap \{ \tau > s \}$.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think about the fact that the set integrating over was in the conditioned sigma algebra!